# How to manually generate JUnit test reports

Tags: java, testing, junit, report

Couldn't come up with a better name. I'm doing something wrong here, please point in the right direction.

I have a small java app. We use Jenkins for CI, and (AFAICT) maven-surefire to generate some nice test reports that Jenkins understands. Now, I needed some sanity/acceptance test for my app. My approach was:

- Configure a Jenkins build that will produce an .rpm package and copy it to a temporary VM, along with acceptanceTest.jar
- The jar effectively has a runner for the JUnit test case that'll fire up some Jetty/MQ servers, install the rpm, update config and check the test servers are being polled/updated as expected.

So far so good - my Jenkins build has a very simple script that does the copying and then runs the jar. If I do it manually, I can see the results on the console.

The problem I now face is generating a test report for Jenkins? maven is not installed on the test VM, nor is ant. Any ideas how I could do this without too much trouble?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is just to install ANT on the test VM. These are the steps:

1. Install ANT
2. Run the JUnit tests with ANT and specify a directory where the test reports will be created.  This is done with the ANT JUnit Task (the [batchtest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task with the *todir* directive)
3. Configure Jenkins build to pick up the reports. This is done under "Post-build actions": there is a checkbox for "Publish JUnit test result report".  Click the checkbox and specify the dir where the test reports are.